Non UFD having unique factorisation, but with an irreducible element which is not prime
Let $R$ be an integral domain. Consider the following properties:
(E) Every $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$ has at least one decomposition $a=u\pi_1\cdots\pi_r, u\in R^\times, \pi_1,\ldots, \pi_r$ irreducibles
(U) Every  $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$ has at most one decomposition, up to permutation and association of the factors
(Eu) Every irreducible element is prime.
It is known that $(E)+(U)\iff (E)+(Eu)$.
We also have $(Eu)\Longrightarrow (U)$.
Question. Is there an example of an integral domain $R$ such that:
(1) $R$ has at least one irreducible element
(2) $R$ has (U) but not (Eu) ?
Clearly, such an example necessarily fails (E). In particular, $R$ is not noetherian.
My two favorite examples of integral domains having (U) and failing (E) are the following:

$R=\{P\in\mathbb{Q}[X]\mid P(0)\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

the ring of entire functions (i.e. holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$).


Unfortunately, these two rings have (Eu).

Out of curiosity, have you seen this article

@rschwieb: NO, i haven't, but it answers perfectly my question. Thank you very much!

Great!  Glad it helps.
